# Review audit - post was apparently deleted for being offensive

Tags: bug, status-declined, disputed-review-audits

Just got caught out by this review audit on Low-Quality Posts queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13962495

The post as appears there looks fine in my opinion, but it was subsequently deleted by community for being spam and or offensive.

Answer (score 1):

The post is actually a product placement link, which is analogous to saying, "Your solution is to use this product!"  That's no different from a link-only answer as without the link, the question isn't really *answered* at all:

> It's a bit strange, but the main difference between npm list and nsp
>   check implementation is that npm list looks at package.json and does
>   directory traversal which is more reliable, while nsp check looks only
>   at package.json.

Feels like this was an okay audit to me.  Be vigilant for link-only answers, even if they're thinly veiled with noise.

Comment: Just to note - it was spam nuked by a mod - it wasn't the only thinly veiled "answer" that user made with that link...

Comment: The part you quoted does look like an answer (to some question) to me...

Comment: I'll go one step further than @JanDvorak: the quoted part, to me, looks like an answer to the specific question it was posted as an answer to. (Note: I do agree with your conclusion, but only because the link by itself is enough to render the answer spam, not because the rest of the post was without content.)